# How to get Heroes of Might and Magic 1 for Windows 95 work in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, windows-95, heroes-of-might-and-magic

I have a collection of old games in a CD (from year approximately 1995). One the games included is Heroes of Might and Magic 1. I would like to get this game working properly on my computer but so far I haven't had any luck. I googled and tried DOSBox with newbie instructions but I couldn't get it to work. I only got a message "This program cannot be run in Dos mode" from DOSBox. I attached a picture that highlights what my game folder includes etc:

[image]

Thank you! P.S. If there's any more information you need, please ask.

UPDATE:

My operating system is:

Windows 7 Home Basic, 64-bit

Comment: What edition (Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, etc) of Windows 7 do you have?

Comment: The game isn't going to run on dosbox because it's not a DOS game. It's a windows 95 game. That said, it's quite unlikely that a 20 year old game is going to work without problem. Might be best to just run a virtual machine for it.

Comment: operating system is Windows 7 Home Basic, 64-bit

Comment: Thank you for your help! What virtual machine should I use? Any instructions? Do I need to get a copy of say Windows XP?

Comment: May I recommend [buying the game on GoG](http://www.gog.com/game/heroes_of_might_and_magic)?  I find that using GoG is often easier than reconfiguring my computer to play an old game.

Comment: Thank you for your help @JasonBerkan I'll consider it x)

Comment: The current [Humble Weekly Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/) has all 6 Heroes of Might and Magic in it if you get the highest tier (which is $15).  As well as Might and Magic 1-6 and X, plus Dark Messiah.  Presumably, these are all updated to run on modern systems.

Comment: Anyways, a simple work around to this problem is to just press F4. That will change the game to full screen. You can then start game and enable sound and maybe music. The original HOMM1 used CD-Audio tracks, which probably aren't on this compilation CD. It might work with 8-bit audio though. Unfortunately it won't remember these settings, it will crash on exit, and you probably can't save. To solve the later problem you need to make the `C:\HEROES` directory writable. Since the CD-ROM is read-only, so is your copy of the CD-ROM.

Answer (score 1):

A simple temporary fix is to press the F4 key. That will change the game to full screen. You can then start the game and enable sound and maybe music. The original version Heroes of Might and Magic used CD-Audio tracks, which probably didn't fit on your compilation CD. It may work with the 8-bit music tracks.

Unfortunately it won't remember these settings and it will likely crash on exit. You might also not be able to save the game because when you copy files from a CD-ROM by copy and pasting them in Explorer they're marked as read-only because the CD-ROM is read-only. You should open your `C:\` folder in Explorer, right click on the `HEROES` folder and select properties. In the property dialog uncheck the "Read-Only" check box and press the OK button. Press OK again so that everything in the folder is made writable. (This step might not actually be necessary, but older games expect to be able to write to the directory they're installed to.)

However the big problem with how you installed the game (simply copying the files from the CD) is that the game's registry settings are missing. This why it starts up in a tiny window in the upper left, why there's no sound or music and why it won't remember these settings after you change them. So you need to create these registry settings yourself. To do this start Notepad, paste the following into it, and save it as a file named `heroes.reg`:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\New World Computing\Heroes of Might and Magic]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\New World Computing\Heroes of Might and Magic\1.0]
"AppPath"="c:\\HEROES"
"CDDrive"="d:"
"Music Volume"=dword:00000002
"Sound Volume"=dword:00000002
"Walk Speed"=dword:00000002
"Show Route"=dword:00000001
"Blackout Computer"=dword:00000000
"Sound Quality"=dword:00000000
"Direct Connect Com Port"=dword:00000000
"Direct Connect Baud Rate"=dword:00000000
"Modem Com Port"=dword:00000000
"Modem Baud Rate"=dword:00000000
"Modem Init String"=""
"Autosave"=dword:00000001
"CD Offset"=dword:00000000
"Slow Video"=dword:00000000
"First Map Offset"=dword:00001649
"Current Map Offset"=dword:00000004
"Main Game Show Menu"=dword:00000000
"Main Game X"=dword:0000000a
"Main Game Y"=dword:0000000a
"Main Game Width"=dword:00000280
"Main Game Height"=dword:000001e0
"Main Game Full Screen"=dword:00000001
"Editor Show Menu"=dword:00000000
"Editor X"=dword:0000000a
"Editor Y"=dword:0000000a
"Editor Width"=dword:00000280
"Editor Height"=dword:000001e0
"Editor Full Screen"=dword:00000001
```

Once you've saved the file, double click on it in Explorer and after asking for confirmation, it should add the necessary settings to the registry.

There's one other potential problem that you've seem to have managed to avoid. The file `WING32.DLL` needs to be installed in the Windows system directory. If it's not installed the game won't run and it'll will complain that the file is missing. Since you didn't receive this error you must already have this file installed on your computer. For anyone else trying to get HOMM1 working on a 64-bit version of Windows you need to copy the `WING32.DLL` file in the game's `WING` subdirectory to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try this today and let you know the result! :)

Answer (score 0):

HOMM has 2 versions: one built for Dos, and one for Windows. You tried running Windows version in DOSBox. I'm not sure can you get the Windows version to work on Windows 7, but you can run the DOS version normally in DOSBox.

If there is no other way to run it in Win 7 (compatibility mode and such) then you need old Win system:

1. run it from DOSBox. You have everything explained on abandonia for [Win3.11](http://www.abandonia.com/vbullet/showthread.php?t=27770) and [Win95](http://www.abandonia.com/vbullet/showthread.php?t=29777). It seems Win98 also works in older version of Dosbox 0.70
2. Use some software for creating virtual machine and installing old Windows

Comment: Hi Marko, welcome to Arqade :), while the links you provided may answer the question, you should quote in the relevant sections into your answer. This way, if the link goes dead, your answer will still be valid.

Comment: @jjepsuomi: you're welcome. I played DOS version of HOMM2 on DOSBox so it's much easier then handling old Windows.

Comment: @Robotnik: Well, I agree about the quotes, but how do I qoute installing old Windows in DOSBox except for "install it in DOSBox". There sre too many steps and things to be aware of. The only permanent and short info is which Windows versions you can get to run. Unless you mean really quoting entire process. I can do that if you think that is what I should have done in the first place. And thank you for editing my answer :)